# Project Euler problem 11, finding adjacent numbers with the greatest sum

Tags: programming-challenge, haskell, functional-programming

The full description of the problem to solve can be found [here](https://projecteuler.net/problem=11). The code I have written works fine but seems extremely verbose for what it's doing, I'm not sure if list comprehensions are meant to be used in the way that I have (maybe some kind of other construct would be more suitable?). Would be great for there to be a way to make the `numberPairs` function to be more DRY.

Also get the sense that I don't use function composition enough `.` and instead use `$` for most nested function calls. Is this bad practice? How could I rewrite some of the functions in this using composition?

I am fairly new to Haskell so am unaware of any typical coding practices.

`gridOfNumbers` evaluates to a string containing the grid numbers from the [problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=11) with each number in a row separated by spaces and each row separated by newlines. Didn't seem worth including here (although I may be mistaken).

```
-- | In the `gridOfNumbers` find the 4 adjacent numbers in the given
-- | direction that have the greatest sum.
problem_11 :: Direction -> Int
problem_11 dir =  
    maximum $ map (\(x1,x2,x3,x4) -> product $ x1:x2:x3:x4:[]) $ numberPairs dir

data Direction = UpDown | SideWays | LeftStartDiagonal | RightStartDiagonal

numberPairs :: Direction -> [(Int,Int,Int,Int)]
numberPairs UpDown = 
    [(x1,x2,x3,x4) | 
     currentRow <- [0..16],
     currentCol <- [0..19],
     let x1 = (listifyGrid !! currentRow) !! currentCol,
     let x2 = (listifyGrid !! (currentRow + 1)) !! currentCol,
     let x3 = (listifyGrid !! (currentRow + 2)) !! currentCol,
     let x4 = (listifyGrid !! (currentRow + 3)) !! currentCol] 
numberPairs SideWays =
    [(x1,x2,x3,x4) |
     currentRow <- [0..19],
     currentCol <- [0..16],
     let x1 = (listifyGrid !! currentRow) !! currentCol,
     let x2 = (listifyGrid !! currentRow) !! (currentCol + 1),
     let x3 = (listifyGrid !! currentRow) !! (currentCol + 2),
     let x4 = (listifyGrid !! currentRow) !! (currentCol + 3)]
numberPairs LeftStartDiagonal =
    [(x1,x2,x3,x4) |
     currentRow <- [0..16],
     currentCol <- [0..16],
     let x1 = (listifyGrid !! currentRow) !! currentCol,
     let x2 = (listifyGrid !! (currentRow + 1)) !! (currentCol + 1),
     let x3 = (listifyGrid !! (currentRow + 2)) !! (currentCol + 2),
     let x4 = (listifyGrid !! (currentRow + 3)) !! (currentCol + 3)]
numberPairs RightStartDiagonal =
    [(x1,x2,x3,x4) |
     currentRow <- [0..16],
     currentCol <- [3..19],
     let x1 = (listifyGrid !! currentRow) !! currentCol,
     let x2 = (listifyGrid !! (currentRow + 1)) !! (currentCol - 1),
     let x3 = (listifyGrid !! (currentRow + 2)) !! (currentCol - 2),
     let x4 = (listifyGrid !! (currentRow + 3)) !! (currentCol - 3)]


listifyGrid :: [[Int]]
listifyGrid = map (map read) doubleListOfStrings 
    where doubleListOfStrings = map (S.split " ") $ lines gridOfNumbers
```

Comment: `product $ x1:x2:x3:x4:[]` could be `product [x1,x2,x3,x4]`

Comment: Yes that's a better way of defining the list in-line. Cheers Landei!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The code I have written works fine but seems extremely verbose for what it's doing ... Would be great for there to be a way to make the numberPairs function to be more DRY.

I agree that there's a fair bit of repetition happening. This makes things very explicit, but at the cost of more boilerplate, as you said.

I suggest that the movement patterns for each direction be separated from the actual functionality of extracting a "line" of adjacent numbers from the board. That way, it's easier to see the differences between each direction:

```
quads :: Direction -> [[Int]]
quads UpDown
    = getLines 4 [0..16] [0..19] succ id
quads SideWays
    = getLines 4 [0..19] [0..16] id succ
quads LeftStartDiagonal
    = getLines 4 [0..16] [0..16] succ succ
quads RightStartDiagonal
    = getLines 4 [0..16] [3..19] succ pred
```

I've renamed `numberPairs` to `quads` because "pair" usually refers to a 2-tuple. `succ` and `pred` are just equivalent to `(+ 1)` and `(- 1)`.

Now you can define `getLines` more generally (albeit with an uglier signature), in terms of iterating the row and column position with the supplied `rowFn` and `colFn`:

```
getLines :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int] -> (Int -> Int) -> (Int -> Int) -> [[Int]]
getLines n rows cols rowFn colFn =
    [line |
     row <- rows,
     col <- cols,
     let coordPairs = zip (iterate rowFn row) (iterate colFn col),
     let line = take n $ map gridGet coordPairs]

gridGet :: (Int, Int) -> Int
gridGet (row, col) = listifyGrid !! row !! col
```

This is just rearranging your code, except that I've used `[Int]` instead of `(Int,Int,Int,Int)` as the type of each number line. I'm not an experienced Haskeller, but I think that, here, the list is considerably easier to deal with than the tuple, at the expense of giving up an explicit length guarantee.

Using a list also makes it easy to adapt to other lengths than 4, since it's just a `take n`. The tuple code, at least structured as you have it right now, would grow linearly.

---

> Also get the sense that I don't use function composition enough . and instead use $ for most nested function calls. Is this bad practice? How could I rewrite some of the functions in this using composition?

Again, keeping in mind that I haven't done a whole lot of Haskell: I don't see anywhere in your code where `$` looks out of place.

One place where composition is nice, though, is with `map` and nested lists. This:

```
listifyGrid :: [[Int]]
listifyGrid = map (map read) doubleListOfStrings 
    where doubleListOfStrings = map (S.split " ") $ lines gridOfNumbers
```

could use composition if you want, as well as the `words` function:

```
listifyGrid = (map . map) read $ map words $ lines gridOfNumbers
```

`(map . map)` is so elegant that the equivalent in Python, for example, just seems obtuse. Oh, Haskell, you charmer.

Anyway, the main `problem_11` function:

```
problem_11 :: Direction -> Int
problem_11 dir =  
    maximum $ map (\(x1,x2,x3,x4) -> product $ x1:x2:x3:x4:[]) $ numberPairs dir
```

can also be defined as a pointfree composition, if that's your style, especially now that we can use `map` directly without unwrapping the tuple:

```
problem_11 = maximum . (map product) . quads
```